# How to override html property created by script (mediaelement.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, overriding, mediaelement.js

for some reason when using mediaelement.js, it creates a div for the progress bar called "mejs-time-rail", but then proceeds to set the html width value to "0" through an inline style.

Since this div is created when the script runs, I cannot edit this property in the source code, but if I edit it (the inline style) in Firefox's inspector, I get the desired result. Also, it seems that this html property created by mediaelement.js overrides any css rules I set.

Any ideas how to circumvent this issue? Maybe editing the actual js script?

Thanks

**I can't post a picture because I don't have enough reputation, but I can update this post with a screenshot when I do have enough and/or if it helps**

Comment: You can always edit it using JavaScript as long as you run your code after the element was created.

Comment: you can always set any css rule with `!important` values on the selector `.mejs-controls div.mejs-time-rail` that won't be overridden http://jsfiddle.net/5bpXK/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it seems the issue is that as the DOM loads, the external script is setting that desired value to 0 like you said.  Try adding a custom JavaScript/jQuery file that simply runs after the DOM is completed and

```
.find the element you want to edit.  Then try
.attr('desiredAttr', 'new val');
```

this should find, and then reset the attribute to whatever you like.  Even if the external script changed it on load.